# iPhone app for easy dictation and sending

Tags: ios, applications, recording

Here is what I want:

I click a button in the app, and I start dictating. When I am done I press OK, and it either sends the sound-file directly to a predefined email or at least prompts me to do so.

Think of it like dictating something and sending the wav/mp3 of it to an assistant straight away.

Does an app like that exist? I tried Googling for dictation apps etc, but could not seem to find a good match.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind an extra step, **Voice Memos** does almost exactly that. It comes with iOS.

1. Run **Voice Memos**
2. Tap **record** (left button)
3. When you're done tap **stop** then **list** (both are the right button, in other words double tap)
4. Select the memo and tap **Share**

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have off course looked at that app and used it some.
The extra steps are the problem in this use case. You press "record", say something then "stop". Then you have to press the "clips" button, press share - and email shows up - and you have to enter the recipient. 
I want to take the pain out of this, since it is the difference between dictating as a no-brainer even for small stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I found something called [Pocket Dictate](http://www.nch.com.au/pocket/index.html), that comes rather close to what I am looking for.

[image]

The most important feature is, that you can set a default email, that you can send to without having to type it in.

The app is not terribly well designed, but so far it is the best I have seen for this specific purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an iPhone 4S, or third-generation iPad, you can use the built-in dictation feature in iOS. This won't send a sound file, but will transcribe your speech to be sent.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Speech to text is not an option, since it never just works. I do have a 4S, but I find Siri to be completely and utterly useless. It simply does not do what I want it to 3 out of 4 times.

Comment: @Kjensen It's interesting to see various people's different experiences with Siri. I use it all the time (many times a day) and it works great for me.

Answer (score 0):

I use DropVox this way. 
If you do need an email it's very easy to make DropBox send you an email when he get a new memo. I do it.

Comment: Please be kind and expand your answer with a link to the mentioned software. Thanks!